# Another Proof Of $A\cup A = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that this is trivial but I'm not sure and I want to understand if and why something is incorrect. I know and understand the proof of $A\cup A = A$ by proving that each set is a subset of the other but I wonder if this is correct too:

$S$: Universe, $A\subseteq S$.

$A\cup A = \{x\in S|x\in A ∨ x\in A\} = \{x\in S|x\in A\} = A.$

Comment: Yes, that works too!  You figured out an important connection between sets and logic!

Comment: $P\vee P\Leftrightarrow P$ is a tautology.

Comment: Recall that $P\lor P = P$